# Getting errors when refreshing an array's object

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, vuejs2

I have an array containing a list of objects (all the posts from a database), and I would like to be able to update one value from object, and refresh the array with the updated object.

Here is the the HTML component that displays all the articles:

```
  <tbody>
    <tr v-for="(post, index) in posts" :key="index">
      <td><router-link :to="`/admin/article/${ post.slug }`">{{  }}</router-link></td>
      <td>{{ post.lang === 'fr' ? 'Français' : 'English' }}</td>
      <td>{{ !!post.draft ? 'Draft' : 'Published' }}</td>
      <td>{{ formatDate(post.created_at) }}</td>
      <td>{{ formatDate(post.updated_at) }}</td>
      <td>
        <div class="actions">
          <span @click="handlePublish(post.id)">{{ !!post.draft ? 'Publish' : 'Unpublish' }}</span>
          |
          <router-link :to="`/admin/article/edit/${post.slug}`">Edit</router-link>
          |
          <span @click="handleDelete(post, index)">Delete</span>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
```

And here is the `handlePublish()` methods that I'm struggling with:

```
handlePublish (id) {
  this.$axios.post('/post/publish', {id: id}, {
    headers: {
      'Authorization': `Bearer <some token>`
    }})
    .then(response => {
      console.log(response) // returns the updated object without trouble
      this.posts = this.posts.map((post, index) => {
        if (post.id === id) {
          return response.data
        }
      })
    })
    .catch(e => console.log(e.response))
}
```

When I trigger the `handlePublish` method, I get errors such as

> "Cannot read property 'slug' of undefined".

The slug is contained in the `router-link` to the content. If I remove it, the error will be about the title.

If I had to take a guess, I'd say the problem happens while VueJS is swapping the old data for the new one.

How can I fix this problem?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add `else` and return the not updated post in the `else` block as follows :

```
      this.posts = this.posts.map((post, index) => {
         if (post.id === id) {
             return response.data
        }else{
          return post;//<----
         }
      })
```

in your code you're returning an array like :

```
  [undefined,undefined,undefined,<updatePost>,undefined,undefined ...]
```

**Example with JS which illustrates the error that you're getting**

```js
let posts = [{
  id: 1,
  content: "aaa"
}, {
  id: 2,
  content: "bbb"
}, {
  id: 3,
  content: "ccc"
}]

let updatedpost = {
  id: 2,
  content: "more content"
};

posts = posts.map(post => {
  if (updatedpost.id == post.id) {
    return updatedpost;
  }
})

console.log(posts)
posts = [{
  id: 1,
  content: "aaa"
}, {
  id: 2,
  content: "bbb"
}, {
  id: 3,
  content: "ccc"
}]

posts = posts.map(post => {
  if (updatedpost.id == post.id) {
    return updatedpost;
  } else {
    return post;
  }
})

console.log(posts)
```

Comment: ... I never thought of that, no wonders why I had no problem when updating an array with only one element in it. Plus, I thought that since there were no "else", all the other elements wouldn't be updated. Thanks a lot!

Comment: you're welcome, i added an example to illustrate the issue that you're getting